# Application crashes when I save image to SD card

Tags: android, eclipse, image

I am trying to use a simple image view and download application, everything works fine till I click on the button to download the application, the moment I click on the button, I get an error saying the application has been closed because it stopped working.

```
package com.theappguruz.imagedownload;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.theappguruz.R;

public class ImageViewAndDownload extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btnImageDownload;
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private ImageView viewDownloadImage;
    private Images imageId;
    private File folderName;
    private String imageName;

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 1) {
                if (pd != null) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
                Utils.showNetworkAlert(ImageViewAndDownload.this);
            } else if (msg.what == 2) {
                if (pd != null) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
                Utils.displayMessage("Image downloade succesfully",
                        ImageViewAndDownload.this);
                // Media scaning
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                        Uri.parse("file://"
                                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

            } else if (msg.what == 3) {
                if (pd != null) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
                Utils.displayMessage("Image already downloaded ",
                        ImageViewAndDownload.this);
            } else if (msg.what == 4) {
                if (pd != null) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
                displayImageFromUrl((Bitmap) msg.obj);
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imagedisplay);

        viewDownloadImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
        btnImageDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnImageDownload);
        imageId = new Images();
        imageName = imageId.getImageId();
        LoadImageFromWeb(Constant.IMAGE_BASE_URL + File.separator + imageName);
        btnImageDownload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnImageDownload) {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(ImageViewAndDownload.this, "",
                    "Downloading Image....", true, false);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        String imageUrl = Constant.IMAGE_BASE_URL
                                + File.separator + imageName;
                        String isDownloded = downloadImage(imageUrl, imageName);
                        if (isDownloded.equalsIgnoreCase("complete")) {
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
                        } else if (isDownloded.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(3);
                        } else {
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        }
    }

    // set display image to Imageview
    public void displayImageFromUrl(Bitmap obj) {
        viewDownloadImage.setImageBitmap(obj);
    }

    // image display from the webview
    private void LoadImageFromWeb(final String url1) {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(ImageViewAndDownload.this, "",
                "Loading Image....", true, false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    URL url = new URL(url1);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();

                    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

                    Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

                    if (options.outWidth > 3000 || options.outHeight > 2000) {
                        options.inSampleSize = 4;
                    } else if (options.outWidth > 2000
                            || options.outHeight > 1500) {
                        options.inSampleSize = 3;
                    } else if (options.outWidth > 1000
                            || options.outHeight > 1000) {
                        options.inSampleSize = 2;
                    }
                    // Do the actual decoding
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

                    is.close();
                    is = getHTTPConnectionInputStream(url1);
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null,
                            options);
                    is.close();

                    if (myBitmap != null) {
                        Message msg = new Message();
                        msg.obj = myBitmap;
                        msg.what = 4;
                        handler.sendMessage(msg);
                    } else {
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public InputStream getHTTPConnectionInputStream(String url1) {
        URL url;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(url1);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            is = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return is;
    }

    // image download code
    public String downloadImage(String imageDownloadUrl, String imageName) {
        // create directory in SDCARD
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            folderName = new File(Constant.STORE_IN_FOLDER);
        else
            folderName = getFilesDir();

        if (!folderName.exists())
            folderName.mkdirs();

        String response = "";
        // create file name and file.
        File storeImageInSDCard = new File(folderName + File.separator
                + imageName);
        if (!(storeImageInSDCard.exists() && storeImageInSDCard.length() > 0)) {
            // start download image
            response = downloadFile(imageDownloadUrl, imageName,
                    folderName.toString());
        }
        return response;
    }

    // start download image
    public String downloadFile(final String url, final String name,
            String foldername) {

        File file;
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        Bitmap myBitmap;
        try {

            URL url1 = new URL(url.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
            System.out.println("Image url :::" + url1);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1
                    .openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // here create a file which define folder name and image name with
            // extension.
            file = new File(foldername, name + ".jpg");
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }

            os.flush();
            os.close();

            // if image size is too large we can scale image than download.
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
            if (options.outWidth > 3000 || options.outHeight > 2000) {
                options.inSampleSize = 4;
            } else if (options.outWidth > 2000 || options.outHeight > 1500) {
                options.inSampleSize = 3;
            } else if (options.outWidth > 1000 || options.outHeight > 1000) {
                options.inSampleSize = 2;
            }
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);

            os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            myBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            myBitmap.recycle();

            return "complete";
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }

    }
}
```

[Link to the LogCat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhJfl.png)
[image]

Comment: You have to post your StackTrace, so we can see what Exception you are getting exactly

Comment: please post your Logcat

Comment: Added Logcat to the OP.

Comment: Check the answers [here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=not%20allowed%20to%20send%20broadcast%20android.intent.action.media_mounted)

Comment: Is that the only error I should be looking to solve?

Comment: Did you add all permissions? like WRITE_EXTERNAL_ STORAGE etc...  pls show  all "use permissions" tags from manifest

Comment: Yes..According to the Logcat that is the only error..

Comment: Permissions from the manifest.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @Lal, should I change "sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
      Uri.parse("file://"
        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));" to "sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, mediaMountUri));"

Comment: Yes..Try that..Might help..

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

First, this was never something appropriate to use.

Second, it is blocked now, because it was never something appropriate to use, and now Google is stopping it on newer versions of Android.

The proper approach is to use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method, or perhaps `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE`.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how I should use the code? I am probably doing something wrong and getting multiple errors.

Comment: @Newbie: This blog post should help: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-files-to-androids-media-library-using-the-mediascanner/

Comment: I managed to fix it but there's a new issue now. It says "Image downloaded successfully" but when I open the gallery it says "No Media Found", do the files go somewhere else on the emulator?

Comment: @Newbie: Well, it may be that you should be downloading the file to one of the directories represented by `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. I don't know enough about your data to know. With respect to a gallery-type app, bear in mind that scanning a file and having it be indexed by the `MediaStore` may not be immediate, though it should be fairly quick. Also, a gallery might not be watching for real-time changes, so you can try getting rid of it (e.g., swipe it off the recent-tasks list) and re-launching it, in case it was open already.

Comment: I tried re-launching and it didn't work. Would you be willing to help me out if I gave you the link to the entire code? I think I am not editing enough for it to go with the MediaScannerConnection edit.

Comment: @Newbie: Sorry, but I cannot really help you directly like that, particularly with apps downloading material that I am not familiar with. While I'm more of a fan of `scanFile()`, as Wolfram's blog post points out, the `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` broadcast is easier. Also, if you are testing on a device, try an emulator, as the problem could be tied to something with the stock gallery-type app on your device. If all that fails, ask a fresh SO question with the code that you are using to try to index the file.